# SharePoint 2010 Unauthorized exception

Tags: search, sharepoint-2010, administrator

I am trying to get search categories from the code (Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.Administration.SearchServiceApplication.Schema.AllCategories). However it throws me UnAuthorized exception( ThrowIfNotSearchAdmin) error.

Has anybody faced and resolved this? Where to configure search administrator in SharePoint 2010?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried to call the code within [SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spsecurity.runwithelevatedprivileges.aspx)?

Answer (score 1):

You should go to

> CA > Manage Service Application > Click on Search Service Application line to get it selected.

In a ribbon click Administrators and add the user which is going to be used to create search categories (if you use **SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges** then it should be your Application Pool Account)!